# Visual Studio 2010 run .exe from command line vs run (f5) debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cout

I am new to c++ and am making a very simple program. All my program does is call a function from the main function, which reads in a text file and returns. To check that I am reading in the file correctly, I am trying to print out the strings I have read in. The print out (cout) works properly when I run from Visual Studio (f5). However, when I run the executable from command line, none of the print outs from my function show up. Only print outs directly in the main function appear. I cannot find a similar question elsewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Most likely, no output shows up, because no strings were read in, because the file was not opened, because the current directory is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run a program from within VC++ the current directory is set to the project directory by default, but the application is by default in a different folder.

E.g. the application may be:

`D:\Work\MyApp\Debug\MyApp.exe`

But the project directory may be:

`D:\Work\MyApp\MyApp\`

When you start the program from outside of VC++ you need to take steps to make sure the current directory is correct, or that the executable and any data files it refers to are in the same folder.

Answer (score 3):

The default working directory for an IDE-launched project in Visual Studio is the *project* folder. This is the folder where you project file resides (the .vcproj or .vcprojx file is the project file).

If the data file you are reading is in the same folder, code like this:

```
std::ifstream inf("datafile.txt");
```

will succeed because the current working folder and the folder where the data file resides are the same.

However, if you switch to where the executable was written (typically this is the project-dir/Debug or project-dir/Release folders) and run the same executable from a command-shell, the data file will not be found.

To test this is the case. Do the following:

1. Open a command prompt.
2. Switch to the project folder where your data file resides.
3. Run the executable with a specified path: `./Debug/YourProgram.exe`, for example.

Note: you can avoid this by having the program take the data file name as an `argv[]` parameter. Then your program will simply use whatever file you tell it to at launch-time.